# select values which not exists in table

Tags: mysql

I have a table (PATHS) with wbout 80.000 records.
The records contains an ID and a PATHID.
For example:

ID :  PATH_ID

---

1  :  102001C31

---

2  :  102001C32

---

3  :  102001C33

---

4  :  102001C34

Now I want to check with one statement which values in my select are not in the table PATHS.

For example if I do this query:
`select * from PATHS where PATH_ID not in (PATH_ID not in ("102001C31","102001C32","102001C3A")`

I get the value "102001C3A back.

Is this possible?

Comment: You want to select from the table some rows that do not exist in the table?

Comment: Yes, I want the selected values back which are not in the table

Comment: You cannot extract from the table information that is not there. There is a solution for your question but for large sets of IDs it is not practical and for small sets of IDs is it not needed. Use `SELECT PATH_ID ... WHERE PATH_ID in (...)` and subtract the resultset from the input list of IDs in the client code.

Comment: yes, after i understood what you want, i think @axiac is right, no way to check that in sql alone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**IF** you place the values you are testing into a table **THEN** you can locate the unmatched rows. Below I have placed the 3 values you are testing into a "derived table" and from that I am able to return the matched row.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5822c/2)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE PATHS
    (
      `ID` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment primary key,
      `PATH_ID` varchar(9))
;

INSERT INTO PATHS
    (`PATH_ID`)
VALUES
    ('102001C31'),
    ('102001C32'),
    ('102001C33'),
    ('102001C34')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select t.path_id
from (
    ## this is an example only ##

    select "102001C31" as path_id union all
    select "102001C32" as path_id union all
    select "102001C3A" as path_id
  ) t
left join paths p on t.path_id = p.path_id
where p.path_id is null
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5822c/2/0)**:

```
|   path_id |
|-----------|
| 102001C3A |
```

Comment: Yes, this is solution. 

I will try to see if the performance is still goed with the table of 80.000 records.

Tx

Comment: I would not suggest using "select ... union all" for 80k rows, i did that for a simple demonstartion, you need to insert the 80k into a table

Comment: I just tested the "select .....  union all " with 500 records against a the paths table of 80.000 records.

In the "select .... union there was 1 path_id which where not in the paths table and the query took about 4 msec.    

PERFECT.